# How can I re-index files from Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

How can I re-index files from Outlook 2007

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these links can help you:

[Repair corrupt Outlook PST files](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1052339.html)

[Inbox Repair Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en;197315&x=11&y=17)

[Oversized PST](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en;296088&x=18&y=6)